# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated vs WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

In an MVC4 app, in a controller logic I want to check if the user is logged in.
Should I use:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Or:

```
WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated
```

As far as I know `WebSecurity` is just a wrapper. Should I use it or `User.Identity` has different functionality ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As far as I know WebSecurity is just a wrapper.

That's correct, both are the same. Let's have a look at how the `WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated` property is implemented:

```
public static bool IsAuthenticated
{
    get
    {
        return Request.IsAuthenticated;
    }
}
```

and now let's look at how the the `WebSecurity.Request` static property is implemented:

```
internal static HttpRequestBase Request
{
    get
    {
        return Context.Request;
    }
}
```

and finally let's have a look at how the `WebSecurity.Context` static property is implemented:

```
internal static HttpContextBase Context
{
    get
    {
        return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    }
}
```

So as you can see:

```
WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated
```

is the same as:

```
new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current).Request.IsAuthenticated
```

which in turn is the same as `Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` with a slight difference that there are null checks and the property will return false if for example the `Identity` property is null.

> Should I use it or User.Identity has different functionality ?

Even if the two are strictly equivalent I would use the `User.Identity` which is the official ASP.NET implementation because if tomorrow you decide to replace the simple membership provider with something else you will have far less things to replace in your code.

Comment: So following your advice, to get the UserId, I won't use WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, and instead use Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey ?

Comment: Yes, the two are also the same. You could use the one you prefer with the same result.