# ajax call does not sent cookies to web api ( Very Strange issue in Web Api)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, asp.net-web-api

Hi this is my ajax code

```
function GetCurrentUserId() {

        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: rootUrl + '/api/Common/CurrentDateAndUser',
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,          
            success: function (data, textStatus, xmLHttpRequest) {
                return data[0];

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                toastr.error('Somthing is wrong', 'Error');
            },



        });

    }
```

When i run this code in IE Browser then i can see this result from quick watch

[image]

See the above image, There have a some `cookies` value in `RequestHeader`

But same time if i run my application in Chrome or Firefox

Then i got this result

[image]

**I can't see any cookies values**. Why? Why i can't see the cookie values when i ran my application in Chrome? How to work the ajax call with Chrome and firefox? I have spend one weeks for this work, i can't solve this. and also Stack overflow does not helps yet. Please share your knowledge to me. please dude's .

### Even a small sliver of wood can help as a toothpick

### Edit

This Question related to my previous question

[Web Security in IE VS Chrome & Firefox (bug)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386532/web-security-in-ie-vs-chrome-firefox-bug)

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit more? What is your goal? What did you try? What is the specific code of `CurrentDateAndUser`? Before you get a decent answer you have to ask a decent question.

Comment: Did you already set `async` to false in the ajax call? And use `http://127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`? Another possible solution is to patch your host file: c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts add the following:
127.0.0.1 test.mydomain.com
Start your webserver within Visual Studio
Close all browsers, then load test.mydomain.com

Comment: Yes, Already did, Why that is the problem? But I need proper solution for that dude. I have a headache for this strange issue. (may be a CORS Issue)

Comment: okay wait i will try that. Do you mean i need host my application in IIS ?

Comment: Where are you debugging? Directly in Visual Studio? Normally Visual Studio starts some kind of server.. What's the server address?

Comment: @GuyT Got a error `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname
`

Comment: You've also to take a look at the portnumber(ip + portnumber = socket).

Comment: Do you have anything in document.cookie in Chrome/FF?

Comment: Browsers should send cookies per default. Can you confirm that you're authenticated in Chrome/FF and have the .ASPX-cookie as @ailerifren suggests? Are you using both http and https at the same time? (That may cause issues if cookies are marked as secure.)

Comment: Since your screenshots on your other question, u actually make a CORS request! I refer to this[http://i.stack.imgur.com/EeLye.jpg] screenshot. U access from port 50949 to port 12345! Can u check the headers of the HTTP response in the fiddler and provide them here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly tell IE to send the cookies to the server `withCredentials: true`

e.g.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    xhrFields: {
       withCredentials: true
    }
 });
```